# Parse date with Ext

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Im trying to parse the following ISO formated date in Ext (Sencha Touch 2), but get it wrong.

I'v looked in the documentation, but its something wrong I do, quite annoying, anyone spotting it?

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Date

From the Chrome console

```
Ext.Date.parseDate('2012-03-06T11:14:28','Y-m-dTH:i:m');
Sun Apr 06 2014 11:14:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to recreate a ISO 8601 parser with simple tokens, that isn't correct. Luckily in the documentation you yourself provided you'll be able to see that it can already parse ISO 8601! ```Ext.Date.parseDate('2012-03-06T11:14:28','c');```

Comment: perfect, worked like charm, thanks! 

please add it as an answer if you want to get answer approved, cant do that on a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to recreate a ISO 8601 parser with simple tokens, that isn't correct.

Luckily in the documentation you yourself provided you'll be able to see that it can already parse ISO 8601!

```
Ext.Date.parseDate('2012-03-06T11:14:28','c');
```